# Find dynamically created text and add heading structure around it

Tags: jquery, html

I have the following div generated when page loads

```
<div id="errorSummary" class="error-summary" style="display:none"></div>
```

After user doesn't enter few fields and clicks next error messages are shown at the top of the page. Then the following div is generated:

```
<div id="errorSummary" class="error-summary" style>
"Please correct the following:"
<ul>
<li>
<a class="message" tabindex="-1" href="#textbox"> Enter first name</a>
</li>
</ul>
</div>
```

I tried the following but it doesn't work. The function fires when page loads but doesn't get fired when the dynamic text is added.

```
$(function () {
        var str = $('.error-summary');
        var match ="Please correct the following:"
        var x = str.text();
        if (x === match) {
            str.html("<h2 tabindex=\"-1\"> Please correct the following</h2> ");
        }
    })
```

I have 2 questions:

1. How to find the dynamically added text "Please correct the following" using jquery or java script.
2. How to add **H2** tags around the text "Please correct the following" dynamically once the text is found.

Comment: `"<h2 tabindex=\"-1\"> Please correct the following</h2> "` is malformed. Maybe it should work but I've never done that. `"<h2 tabindex='1'>"+match+"</h2>");`

Comment: the function itself is not firing when dynamic text is added.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The reason your code ins'nt getting fired later and getting fired on page load , because its an anonymous function ,which will only get fired only at page load and not after that, But as per your requirement you should explicitly call function as per your logic.
**Use/call following code once error  container is shown when user hasn't typed anything in input field**

```
var html = $(".error-summary").html();
        if($(".error-summary").text().indexOf("Please correct the following:")!=-1)
        {
            html = html=html.replace('Please correct the following:','<h2 tabindex=\"-1\"> Please correct the following</h2>');
            $(".error-summary").html(html);
        }
```

**Copy this code at the same place just below where container is shown.**

Answer (score 1):

**Q1: How to find dynamically added text**

After the text is dynamically added to the page, you can use jQuery to query for the selector holding said text and use the jQuery `text()` method to obtain the text.

```js
$(function(){
 //This will be my dynamically added text or html
 var str = '<a href="google.com">Here</a>';
 //Since my string IS holding html I want to use html() method
 //And set the html or text of the selector
 $('.main').html(str);
 //After the selector has received the dynamically created content
 //I find the text that was previously dynamically added
 var tx = $('.main').find('a').text();
 console.log(tx)
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="main"></div>
```

**Q2: How to add H2 around another element**

For this, simply find the element you wish to 'wrap' and use the jQuery method `wrap()`;

```js
$(function(){
  //this will find the dynamically created element, then wrap it with an h2
  $('.main').find('a').wrap('<h2 />');
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="main">
  <a href="google.com">Google</a>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Where is the element with class "validation-summary"?  This should work:

```
<div id="errorSummary" class="error-summary" style>
<span class="validation-summary">"Please correct the following:"</span>
<ul>
<li>
<a class="message" tabindex="-1" href="#textbox"> Enter first name</a>
</li>
</ul>
</div>
```

Comment: sorry my bad its not validation-summary. i am updating the question

Comment: I think if you left it as validation-summary, and did what I suggested you may be okay.  Otherwise, gettint the .text() value of your .error-summary div and setting the .html() will throw off all of the other html within that div.  A jsfiddle could help if you have time to set that up